# Exclude in DecorateAllWith, using structuremap

Tags: ioc-container, structuremap

I used following code to decorate all my `ICommandHandler<>` with `Decorator1<>`, using `structuremap`:

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
{
....
    x.For(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
     .DecorateAllWith(typeof(Decorator1<>),
                  instance => instance.ReturnedType.Assembly == typeof(Class1).Assembly);
}
```

Is there any way to exclude one of my concrete `CommandHandlers` from this decoration?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the question, but can't you just alter the supplied predicate? You can write anything you want inside that predicate including code that excludes a particular handler.

Comment: @Steven for example how can I exclude TestCommandHandler?

Comment: How would you do this if you were filtering a list using C# code?

Comment: @Steven sorry, I don't understand the relation between my question and your comment, I want to to exclude a `CommandHandler` in using structure map.